Using Joi raw() with default()
I'm currently working with Joi for validation purposes and encountered an issue regarding date formatting and default values. Here's the scenario:
date: Joi.date().format("YYYY-MM-DD").raw().default(DateTime.now().toISODate())
I want date to default to the current date (e.g., "2024-04-15") when it's undefined. However, without using .raw(), this works fine. But the problem arises when I send date: "2024-04-15". Joi automatically converts it to date: 2024-04-15T00:00:00.000Z, which is not what I want.
Note:

I am using "@joi/date": "^2.1.0" extension to be able to use format function
I am using "luxon": "^3.0.1" to use DateTime.now().toISODate() which returns string e.g.:  "2024-04-15"

I've tried above also with changing the order of raw and default invocations
Expectations:

If I send {date: "2024-03-10"} I want Joi to return {date: "2024-03-10"}
If i send {} I want Joi to return current default date e.g.: {date: "2024-04-15"}

How can I maintain the default date format while properly handling undefined values in Joi validation? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
